# Building from 2015 on a 2012 server?

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to build a solution from Visual Studio 2015 using a 2012 TFS Server?

I'v been trying to do just that, and for some reason I am having issues with the server reading my config file. I don't know if this is related to backwards compatability, but I would like to know whether it is possible to build **from VS 2015 on a TFS 2012 server?**

Comment: should be possible if you install c#6 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, refer to this link for details: [Running Tests with Visual Studio 2015 on a TFS2012 Build Server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46be308c-e579-4fa2-be13-e93a7d4d04df/running-tests-with-visual-studio-2015-on-a-tfs2012-build-server?forum=tfsbuild)